# Regex to find all strings between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Find string between two strings. I am getting only first group but there are more strings that matches regex but I don't know what I am missing. Below is my regex.

```
(?<="product": ")(.*?)(?=")
```

Input: `{"product": "product1"},{"product": "product2"},{"product": "product3"}`

Output: `product1, product2, product3`

Output will be in groups but yeah final output will be list of products.

Also see this, 
https://regex101.com/r/kGdgjY/1/

Comment: It's a part of a JSON string. Parse the JSON if you have an entire JSON string, otherwise add square brackets to transform it into a JSON array. Whatever, don't use regex to do that.

Comment: The problem is that is a part of string. And there is no other way to parse it other than regex

Comment: Just use the `/g` (for **g**lobal) flag, but I agree - regexing JSON is a hack, I would find a way to parse the JSON.

Comment: @displayname: In this case show the entire string.

Comment: @i-- It can be dupe of both, just close the question and we'll add both as close reasons (it is possible to add up to 5 close reasons).

Comment: Most of the time, this kind of questions are about a JSON string with an header that is easy to remove. That's why without to know what is the exact context, I don't close the question.

Comment: All of them gives output for 1st group matched only.

Comment: Thanks guys for the revert. I have updated question. I hope this will provide more info.

Comment: Is it the entire string or a part already extracted from another string?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Input could be something like this
Input `This are the list of products {"product": "product1"},{"product": "product2"},{"product": "product3"} and list of regions {"region": "region1"},{"region": "region2"},{"region": region3"}` So highlighted one is the whole string it can contain any random data as its a log of a application

Comment: What's wrong with `"product":\s*"([^"]+)"`? Live demo https://regex101.com/r/Ccivny/1

Comment: @revo Yeah that would do the job. Thanks. I hope it was not duplication.

Comment: @displayname: show the real string, not something you think it describes your real string. I think you have missing something easy to split the part that is JSON from the other part of the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Check my previouse message where i tagged you. Highlighted will be the actual input, 

`This are the list of products {"product": "product1"},{"product": "product2"},{"product": "product3"} and list of regions {"region": "region1"},{"region": "region2"},{"region": region3"}`